# Questions regarding Using AlarmManager with locked screen

Tags: android, wakelock, keyguard

So I basically know how to use AlarmManager and unlock the screen and key guard to run the activity . Here is the code i am using

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
    PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
    wl.acquire();
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

now it basically does what its intended to do. It wakes the screen and unlocks the key guard and runs the activity
But i had a few questions

1)What would happen if the person has a passcode setup on his lock Screen. I read it asks the user to unlock the screen first

2)If i wanted to run the activity that basically plays an alarm and shows some text could i do it without unlocking the screen? Like a normal alarm or music player work. And have a button that does some further task without needing to unlock the screen

What i basically want to do is play an alarm when the activity is fired. And if the user pushes a button , it should play another sound. is there a way to achieve this without asking the user to enter his pass code ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is not the simple (slide lock), but a code or pattern, then user will have to unlock first. Otherwise a malicious app could just override any security screen.
2. I think you could play sounds etc. But to show something on lock screen you'd need window flags [`FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED) and optionally [`FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD).

Basically, `getWindow.addFlags(FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);` would show this (and only this) activity as an insecure content, on top of the lock screen. You can put the interaction UI here.

Comment: so with getWindow.addFlags(FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED); can i add a button to the activity ? and will the button work without unlocking the screen ?

Comment: and getWindow.addFlags(FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED); is only used to show full screen activity i read somewhere , what if i have a dialog activity ? will it work then

Comment: @user2557844 This will make the window show on the top of lock screen. It doesn't matter what you put on that window. Yes, Activities and dialogs have their own separate windows.